# Criteria for storing calculation results versus making calculations at run time

Tags: optimization, mysql

One of my clients is a golf site.  Every couple of weeks they come up with a new statistic they want available in various reports on individual rounds and covering all rounds.

For instance the percentages of putts made versus missed when attempted with under 10 feet of distance.

Some parameters:

1. report viewings occur more often than new record entries
2. Reports needs to run as quickly as possible and this is higher priority than saving quickly
3. Every hole in a round has a record
4. Every round has a record
5. Every user has a lifetime stats record
6. We are storing over 250 individual datapoints per round (holes record included)
7. The stats pages display about 100 individual calculations

My current approach has been to add fields to the hole/round/lifetime stats tables as new stats are needed and to calculate stats every time a round is saved.

The problem is that at some point we may well exceed mySQL's maximum row size of 65535 bytes.

So, the questions are:

1. Is there a point where I should start calculating statistics on the fly instead of storing them?
2. Alternately should I just plan on adding new stats tables to hold the overflow?

Comment: Please tell me your are **not** storing all your data in one big table. see: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: There are about 45 tables.  users, courses, tees, rounds, holes, stats all have tables.  All tables have auto-incremented primary indices and reference foreign keys as needed eg rounds references userid; hole references roundid; tee references courseid etc.

Comment: Also bridging tables are used as needed for things like coaches-to-students (many-to-many)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have indexes on the `date`,  `hole`, `user` and  `round` fields it should take very little time to calculate the lastest stats.

```
SELECT s.*           
       , 1 - perc_missed as perc_hit
FROM (
  SELECT IFNULL(putts_missed / total_putts,1) as perc_missed
         ,player
         ,hole 
  FROM golf_stats gs
  WHERE gs.playdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'
  GROUP BY gs.player, gs.hole ) AS s;
```